# Find the number of ways to distribute 52 cards to four distinct people with 13 cards each, if the cards are (a) distinct, (b) identical.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Find the number of ways to distribute $52$ cards to four distinct people
>   with $13$ cards going to each person, if
>
> (a) the cards are distinct;
>
> (b) the cards are identical

(a) The function $\{\text{52 distinct cards}\} \to \{\text{4 different people}\}$ is a bijection and so by Twelvefold Way, the answer is $52!$, but  this answer overcounts by a factor of $(13!)^4$. Thus the actual answer to (a) is $\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}$

(b) This problem is identical to the one that asks how many ways there are to put $4$ identical balls in $4$ distinct boxes such that each box gets no more than one ball. By the Twelvefold Way, the answer must be $1.$

I'd like to know if this reasoning works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reasoning looks good and makes sense. I would also like to note that you may also answer part (a) with multinomial coefficients.

If you're ever unsure you've done a counting problem correctly, you can always try out your answer/formula out on a smaller case. For instance, what if we had 6 distinct cards that we wanted to distribute evenly to three people? It is essentially the same question as part (a), just different numbers. You could solve it with the reasoning you used, and you can also count it by enumerating all the possibilities. This is a good, not foolproof, check on your reasoning.